# Query user permission level for an object's parent?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, soql

I have a custom object with a master-detail to opportunity. Is there a way to determine if the user has read or read/write access when querying this custom object?

To clarify my needs, I'm looking for a way to render my page (non-visualforce) with a clear distinction between records they have only read access to and records in which they may edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user will have the same access to that as they have to the opportunity. The `Profile` object exposes permissions but it doesn't appear to allow you to find out about CRUD settings for objects.

Are you creating an integration piece or working with Visualforce? If you're using Visualforce the interface will respect security controls automatically, hiding data they're not allowed to see and making fields read only when using `<apex:inputField>` if they do not have permission to write to the field.

** Edit ** 
Maybe somebody will have a better solution, but how about trying to update the records you query, storing whether each was a success or failure, and then using that to control the interface? Bit of a hack, if I find anything else I'll be sure to update.

** Edit 25/01/2012 **
Have just come across this: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm?SearchType=Stem

Pretty sure that'll give you exactly what you need!

Comment: Integration, so ideally I'd like to have this info at the same time I query for the records. I know there's an OpportunityShare object which has some permission info, but I'm not sure if it's the right stuff or if I can even get to that when querying my custom object.

Comment: Have just updated my answer to include some new found information :)

Comment: I hoped to avoid any extra queries, but at least I can get the permissions for all rows in just one extra shot with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might contain answer to your question http://salesforceblogger.blogspot.com/2012/04/query-user-access-level-in-apex.html

There is an UserRecordAccess table which is exposed with API 24.0 with which u can easily check for access instead of banging ur head with share object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to query to find out the level of access however if your apex class uses the With Sharing keyword it will respect sharing on the object thus when you attempt to update the data you'll get a DML exception which you could catch.

If you're not using With Sharing then apex doesn't respect the Sharing model and technically the user will be able to update the data even if they don't have access.

As pointed out by LaceySnr if you're using visualforce the `<apex:inputfield>` element will display read-only automatically to the user if they only have ReadOnly Access.

Comment: I'd like to be able to render the page with a visual difference between the records the user may and may not edit, so handling the failure from the controller isn't quite a solution. I edited my original post to clarify a bit.